# height:100%; works, but min-height:100%; doesn't work?

Tags: css

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9Gmx/

How can I get min-height:100%; to work?

Comment: you can use just height , if there will be much data , page height will automatically raise up

Comment: There's, like, less than ten lines of code. Why not *post that* in the question, so we don't have to open *yet another tab* to answer a basic question? (And, y'know, thanks for the fiddle and all...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* working, but since the div's parent (body) doesn't have a height, 100% is essentially zero pixels. Set the body's height to 100% and you'll get the effect you want.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j9Gmx/2/